# Sampling from elliptic pde solution in high dimensions

Tags: probability, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, large-data, differential-equations

What is known about sampling from solutions to elliptic PDE's in high dimensions, where it is computationally infeasible to construct or store the actual solution?

For example, let $u$ solve the Poisson equation $\Delta u = f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard decay condition at infinity, and $n \approx 100$. Assuming $f$ is sufficiently nice so that $u$ can be normalized. How can we draw samples from the normalized version of $u$, interpreted as a probability distribution?

**Edit:** My first guess would be from analogy with the physical origins of the Poisson equation, where $f$ can be interpreted as a source of fluid that flows out diffusively. The idea would be to interpret $f$ as a probability distribution, randomly draw from $f$, then do a random walk from there for a sufficiently long time to get a draw from $u$.

Comment: Do you have analytic expression of your PDE solution?

Comment: No, nor is it likely there is an analytic solution

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that either $f$ or $u$ are probability density functions?

Comment: I'm considering the normalized version of $u$ and $f$ as probability density functions of interest. From the PDE theory, the solution $u$ can be controlled by the data $f$, even adding 2 extra degrees of smoothness, so $u$ should be normalizable if $f$ is.